# Newer mpd for 18.04

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, 32-bit, mpd

Is there an easy way of installing mpd 0.21.20 or newer in Ubuntu 18.04? The machine has 32 bit Ubuntu.

I currently have version 0.20.18-1build1 from bionic/universe i386 Packages installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [*cp.piber's misc packages* PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecppiber/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=bionic) with newer `mpd` version for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cppiber/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mpd
```

Comment: I did not have to do `apt-get update` part explicitly.

Comment: That repository does not seem to be available anymore.

Comment: There is also https://launchpad.net/~dtl131/+archive/ubuntu/mpdbackport but it does not support bionic (i.e. 18.04) let alone 32 bit.

Comment: I found this now, and since I needed them as well, I uploaded them to my ppa: https://launchpad.net/~cppiber/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: @ConstiP thanks, great. MPD from your PPA installs and runs normally.